# How do I set up the books for LLC taxed as a C-Corp?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, bookkeeping

Most resources online for bookeeping for LLCs immediately repeat a myth about C-Corp taxation subjecting you to double-taxation, declare that nobody would set up their single-member LLC as anything but an S-Corp, and then proceed to talk about S-Corp taxation and bookkeeping.

In an S-Corp, profit isn't taxed at the business level; it's taxed on the owner's income.  The owner puts money into the business and gets an owner draw (the business's bank accounts are *your* bank accounts, and you can give the owner equity to yourself).

In a C-Corp, there is no owner draw.  Owners get money out of the business by:

- Salary and bonuses (wage income) paid as *reasonable compensation* (paying yourself less or more than reasonable compensation will net you angry letters from the IRS)
- Rent paid to owner properties
- Shareholder dividends

Shareholder dividends are legal only from profits.  Net operating profits are taxed at 21% (was 35% in 2016); dividends are then taxed at 15%.

Cash compensation and rent are *business expenses* and aren't taxed at the business level.

So here's the fun part:  if I put $100,000 into my business, I have as much owner equity as if I put $1 in and loan my business $99,999.  Once the business pays off the loan, all the assets of the business *also* belong to me.  As the sole owner, no matter what I invest, 100% of the assets of the business belong to me.  As I understand, if I *invest* $100,000, I can't get that back into my own pocket without paying taxes.

Is that right?

Another fun fact:  LLCs don't have stock.  An LLC as a C-Corp is taxed as a C-Corp, but it does *not* have Corporate shareholders—that is, it does not have what the SEC calls "stock".

So how do I set up the books for an LLC taxed as a C-Corp?  It's different from an LLC taxed as an S-Corp, and different from a Corporation, isn't it?

What do these accounts look like?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way LLCs are set up in the US (hence this is just a comment for you to consider perhaps amending your question), but the article [What Type of Stock for a C Corporation?](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/type-stock-c-corporation-74836.html) seems to imply that C Corporations *do* issue stock.

Comment: "Shareholder dividends are legal only from profits." I don't think this is true - companies with negative earnings pay dividends all the time. Note that you can still have positive _cash flow_ and negative net profit.

Comment: There is almost no reason to set up an LLC as a C-Corp if you are a single owner/100% shareholder (this opens you up to double taxation with no real advantages). Please consult a tax attorney...LLC's don't have "stock" but they do have the concept of "shares".